# How to pass a resolved promise value to another function?

Tags: json, node.js, axios

How do I pass the the returned `Promise` value to another function? I need to retrieve a parsed `JSON` data and then **use that response data** to send to Slack channel.

My index.js

```
// Get the data
let getData = () => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(res => {
        const responseJSON = res.data
        return responseJSON
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`Error in getData(): ${err}`)
    })
}

// Post to Slack (real-time)
let slack = () => {
    axios.post('url-to-post-to', {
            'text':  getData().toString() // This has to be a string, but right now it's returning [object Promise]
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(`Error in SLACK: ${err.response.data}`)
        })
}
```

Right now I'm getting `[object Promise]` in Slack channel, but I need the `JSON` that is returning in a form of **string**.

I think that I'm trying to pass a value that has not yet been resolved, but the problem is, I don't know how to pass the value after it has been resolved.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert your Slack call *thenabled* after your first call. You need to this because as you suspect, you are doing the Slack call with the result of an unfulfilled promise.

```
// Get the data
let getData = () => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(res => {
        const respondeJSON = res.data;
        return responseJSON;
    }).then(data => {
        axios.post('url-to-post-to', {
            'text': data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(`Error in SLACK: ${err.response.data}`);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(`Error in getData(): ${err}`)
    })
};
```

Comment: I needed to add one more `.then()` to the chain (Second `.then()` so that it has 3 .then()'s eventually) because it was returning `[object Object]`. The second `.then()` is this: `.then(resData => { const returnedJSON = JSON.stringify(resData) return returnedJSON})` and after that comes the `.then(data => axios.post(...)`. But your answer and from another user gave me better explanation on how to pass a value from the promise.

Answer (score 1):

When working with promises, if a promise is returned from a function you can call the then property on it, and the resolved value is passed through the then paramater. You could do.

```
// Get the data
let getData = () => {
    return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(res => {
        const respondeJSON = res.data
        return responseJSON
    })
    .catch(err => {
       console.log(`Error in getData(): ${err}`)
    })
}

// Post to Slack (real-time)
let slack = () => {
    getData().then(data => 
    axios.post('url-to-post-to', {
           'text':  data.toString() 
         })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`Error in SLACK: ${err.response.data}`)
    }))
}
```

or

```
// Get the data
let getData = () => {
    return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(res => {
        const respondeJSON = res.data
        return responseJSON
    })
    .catch(err => {
       console.log(`Error in getData(): ${err}`)
    })
}

// Post to Slack (real-time)
let slack = (data) => {
    axios.post('url-to-post-to', {
           'text':  data.toString() 
         })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`Error in SLACK: ${err.response.data}`)
    }))
}

getData().then(slack);
```

Comment: This one and the answer above, worked. I'll upvote both, but verify the one that is more readable.

Comment: Your answer works, but the answer from Dez is shorter and more readable. If I could verify 2 answers, I would verify yours too.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function in `async-await`.

```js
let slack = async () => {
    axios.post('url-to-post-to', {
            'text':  await getData().toString()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(`Error in SLACK: ${err.response.data}`)
        })
}
```

Comment: `invalid_payload`

Comment: Depending on the node version he might not have available async / await. He needs to use > v.8 for having it by default, or late v.7 versions (> v.7.6.0). .

Comment: It might be the case.

Comment: It's `v9.5.0`. 2 people who have posted their answers, their answers are working. But I appreciate your willing to help me.

Comment: Please check the updated code, if it works for you. I have added `getData().toString()` instead of `getData()`.

Comment: without `toString()` Slack would log the `no_text` error, not the `invalid_payload` error. I got it to get it working by using the code provided by Dez. Once again I appreciate your help.